# Google Appscript IF Or statement not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good day everyone; I am running into an error I can't explain.  The scenario is as follows, I have two input boxes that collect information.  If no value is entered, I want the if statement to handle it and cause a break.  The Input box also has an "x" to close the box, which returns a value of "Cancel".  What I am trying to do is capture a condition where if no value is entered OR cancel is passed through, a break will occur.  Right now, the problem is Google completely ignores the Or statement.  I know individually, my IF logic works, but when coupled with OR it doesn't recognize the condition.

This is my current code:

```
          var propnumber = Browser.inputBox('Enter RFI/RFQ Number', Browser.Buttons.OK);
          
          if(propnumber != "" || propnumber != 'cancel'){} else{
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('You must enter a value')
            return
          };
          var myName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the Component Name",Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

          if(myName != 'cancel')
          {
                  I do something
          }
```

As I mentioned in my description, my propnumber condition ignores the or and always accepts the value of cancel or blank.  If I remove the or ( || ) then it works with one condition at a time.

I am sure this is something trivial any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's wrong

The logic in the following part of your code

```
if(propnumber != "" || propnumber != 'cancel'){
    // I assume some code will go here
} else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('You must enter a value')
    return
};
```

does not match the logic you've described here:

> if no value is entered OR cancel is passed through, a break will occur.

Consider the case where `propnumber` is `'cancel'`:

`propnumber != ""` evaluates to `true`

`propnumber != 'cancel'` evaluates to `false`

Therefore the `if(... || ...)` condition in your code evaluates to `true` and the (currently empty) `if` block runs, rather than the `else`.

### How to fix it

Option 1: A literal translation of the logic

> if no value is entered OR cancel is passed through, a break will occur

would be

```
if(propnumber == "" || propnumber == 'cancel') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('You must enter a value')
    return
} else {
    // Some action
}
```

Option 2: If you wish to swap the `if` and `else` clauses, you must negate the *entire* condition.  So this will also work:

```
if(!(propnumber == "" || propnumber == 'cancel')) {
    // Some action
} else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('You must enter a value')
    return
}
```

Note the added parentheses and single negation.

Option 3: use AND instead of OR in your existing code.

The expression `!(A || B)` is NOT logically equivalent to `!A || !B`.  Instead, it is equivalent to `!A && !B` (see [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).  So this will also work:

```
if(propnumber != "" && propnumber != 'cancel') {
    // Some action
} else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('You must enter a value')
    return
}
```